# selenium webdriver SendKeys is not working

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

```
public void testMedicalPartyTraffic(){
    doLogin(true);
    chooseDataset("Party");

    new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("searchId"))).selectByVisibleText("Medical Party Traffic");
    driver.findElement(By.id("chk_iiProviderId")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("chk_iiProviderId")).sendKeys(Keys.DELETE);
    ****driver.findElement(By.id("chk_iiProviderId")).sendKeys("HOSP_PROV000000002");****
    driver.findElement(By.id("btnSubmit")).click();

    WebElement table = waitForDataTable(1, 1, "dataTable");
    doubleClickByRowAndColumn(table, 1, 1);

    waitForText("_divScreenTitle", "Party");
}
```

I am using Chrome Browser and ChromeDriver instance and Selenium WebDriver 2.49.1.

The `sendKeys` method is not sending any input string into the browser. Is there any alternative method to set a String into a text field?

Provider ID:

I have a dropdown with three option on the left hand side of the webpage. When the default first option is selected from the dropdown the sendKeys is working fine . But when i select the second option from the dropdown the sendKeys method is not passing the string into the text filed .

Comment: Change `.sendKeys(Keys.DELETE)` to `.clear()` and try again. Also, you don't need to click in the field before send a string or a key.

Comment: I tried clear() method initially and i was getting some weird error so i changed it back to keys.DELETE which is working fine . Tried by commenting out click method , still no luck :(

Comment: Are you input inside a iframe tag? It can cause weird errors. No problems should be appears using clear method, but any item inside an iframe needs be accessed in a different way to works

Comment: try by giving thread.sleep may be 1 sec before and after sendkeys. some times it helps me

Comment: @striter Alfa : No i am not in i frame tag .

Comment: @muraliseleniumtrainer : Tried giving thread.sleep but no luck .The string value is not being passed into the text field .

Comment: Please, edit the post with the html that you're trying to send keys in Selenium

Comment: This is going to be very difficult if we can't see the errors and have no way of recreating the problem. Can you please try to minimise your testcase so that it's runnable by others?

Comment: <div class="row">
<input id="chk_iiProviderId" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" onclick="toggleElement(this, 'iiProviderId')">
<label class="formLabel" for="iiProviderId">Provider ID:</label>
<input id="iiProviderId" class="textField floatRight" maxlength="4000" disabled="true" value="" name="iiProviderId">
<div id="div_iiProviderId" class="equalTo" onclick="toggleEqualTo(this, $('#hid_iiProviderId'), $('#chk_iiProviderId'));"></div>
<input id="hid_iiProviderId" type="hidden" value="false">
</div>